# INSERT en BD con PRESTASHOP

Tags: insert, prestashop, base-de-datos

Estoy tratando de hacer un insert a una tabla en la base de datos de PRESTASHOP pero no logro conseguirlo.

```
    Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO ps_test(PLAZO)
            VALUES ("test")';
```

Me pregunto si antes debo iniciar una conexion en mi clase o que debo realizar?

Comment: Si la query la pones despues del execute desde luego es normal que no funcione.

Comment: Entonces cual seria la forma correcta?

Comment: La consulta va antes de execute() pues así como la tienes interpreta ejecutar lo que tiene sql pero en esa línea aún no sabe qué contiene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás intentando ejecutar un query que defines posteriormente, solo cambia el orden:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO ps_test(PLAZO)
        VALUES ("test")';
Db::getInstance()->execute($sql);
```